# swift static protocol functions called generically from array

Tags: swift, types, casting, protocols, extension-methods

I have a project in which i want to document by structs in a certain way. Each struct should have a static method document which returns a String. I wanted to write an extension for `Array` so that i can call the function on an array of objects conforming to my protocol, but it's not working..

So far I got this:

```swift
protocol Documentable {
  static func document() -> String
}

extension Array: Documentable where Element == Documentable {
  static func document() -> String {
    guard let casted = Element.Type.self as? Documentable.Type else {
      return "didn't work..."
    }

    return "[\(casted.document()), ...]"
  }
}

struct StructA: Documentable {
  static func document() -> String {
    return "a"
  }
}

// approach 1
// this leads to "didn't work..."
let a = Array<StructA>()
print(type(of: a).document())

// approach 2
// referencing static method 'document()' on 'Array' requires the types 'StructA' and 'any Documentable' be equivalent
let b = Array<StructA>.self
print(b.document())
```

Approach 1 compiles, but leads to a runtime error because the casting somehow doesn't work, which I feel like makes little sense, since `Element` has to conform to my protocol, so the cast should always work..

Approach 2 doesn't compile with the message:

```
referencing static method 'document()' on 'Array' requires the types 'StructA' and 'any Documentable' be equivalent
```

which is also weird because `StructA` does conform to my protocol..

it may have something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) but i'm not sure how to do this then..

Comment: I think somebody should forbid already making static members in protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code adds an extension on the single type of `Array<Document>`, not `Array<T>` for all `T` that conforms to `Document`.

`Element.document()` obviously cannot exist for `Array<Document>`. Since `Element` is the same as `Document`, `Element.document()` has no implementation. See also [the post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

You should change `==` to `:`. That's probably what you meant to do.

```
extension Array: Documentable where Element: Documentable {
    static func document() -> String {
        "[\(Element.document()), ...]"
    }
}
```

And now you can do `Array<StructA>.document()`, and that will return `"[a, ...]"`.